# Can I add a method to a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

This is sort of what closures are meant to avoid, but I'm wondering if there's a way to a add a method to a closure.  Basically I have a js file library that I'd like to augment for a specific client by adding a new method.

I have a js file called library:

```
var LIBRARY = (function(){
var name;
return {
setName: function(n) { name = n; }
}());
```

but for a new client I want to give them a new js file that will just augment LIBRARY, adding a new function:

```
function(first, last){
name = first + " " + last;
}
```

I don't want to have to modify the library js though.  Is there any way to append this function to LIBRARY so that the function has the necessary access to the *name* variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just wanted to leave a note on how I actually accomplished this because it underscores a different way of thinking about architecture in JS.

As mentioned, I wanted to be able to augment my library with client-specific functions.  What I ended up doing was modifying my library to read something like:

```
var LIBRARY = (function(){
 var name;
 var settings;
 return {
  init: function(options){ 
    jQuery.extend(settings, options); // just merges two objects together
   }
  setName: function(n) { name = n; }
  custom: function(){
    if (!settings.custom || typeof(settings.custom == 'function'))
      return;
    name = settings.custom.apply(this, arguments);
  }
 }());
```

Then the client library augments my LIBRARY with a function like so:

```
LIBRARY.init({ custom: function(first, last) {
 return first + " " + last;
} });
```

so now client code can call:

```
LIBRARY.custom("static", "hippo");
```

and *name* will be set to "static hippo"

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you can't — or at least, not in a reasonable way. Only the functions defined within that closure will have access to that local variable.

The unreasonable way to do this would be to play games with `eval`, but I'd strongly advise against it.

All you can do is add functions to `LIBRARY` that don't need direct access to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you envisioned the "appending", but this works

```
// Base
var LIBRARY = (function(){
  var name;
  return {
      setName: function(n) { name = n; }
    , getName: function() { return name; }
  }
}());

// Extension
LIBRARY.setFullName = function( first, last )
{
  this.setName( first + " " + last );
}

// Test
LIBRARY.setFullName( 'Peter', 'Bailey' );
alert( LIBRARY.getName() );
```

Comment: i was hoping to be able to go directly without exposing the name variable (though the setName only exposes a setter it's not idea).  might have to go this route though

Comment: @statichippo: This really is your only option barring (again) using `eval`, which is just a can of worms.

Comment: i'm not even considering the eval path.  eval is just one letter away from evil ;)